# Access to premarket data without displaying it

Tags: pine-script

I was trying to create an indicator to draw pre-market low/high levels automatically, which is an integral part of many charting titles, but it seems that I've got stuck.

I wondered if PineScript can access pre-market data for an instrument without displaying pre-market data itself, i.e., without setting the "Extended Trading Hours" option, which breaks all trendlines and defeats the purpose?

I've tried to see the source code for indicators like "HL levels" in hopes of resolving my issue, but they don't seem to work while displaying Regular Trading Hours charts.

As a Premium membership holder, I was also trying to reach out the customer service, hoping for a premium answer. Alas, they referred me to the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your script will be executed on each bar. If you don't have extended hours enabled, then there are no bars for the extended session. So, no data for the extended trading hours.

---

## **Edit:**

`session` parameter of the `ticker.new()` is just a way of including the extended session in your calculations or not. It will not provide you any data that is not on your chart.

Look at the below example. Extended hours are enabled but I am requesting data specifically from the regular session.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Example 2: Extended Session Data")
t = ticker.new("BATS", "AAPL", session.regular)
cc = request.security(t, timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_on)
plot(cc, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

Now, look at this example. Extended hours are enabled and I am requesting these bars to be included.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Example 2: Extended Session Data")
t = ticker.new("BATS", "AAPL", session.extended)
cc = request.security(t, timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_on)
plot(cc, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

And finally, same code but this time extended hours is disabled.

[image]

As you can see, there is no data for the bars that are not on your chart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciate it! I was wondering if the security function has the ability to retrieve additional data without actually displaying it. PineScript v5 has the 'ticker.new' function, that has 'session' parameter which could be set to 'session.extended'. It is very unclear what it actually does and if there are any real data available for the script.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for! A little sad though, this is a sort of basic functionality that is completely missing from the platform...

Answer (score 2):

You can access extended hours data on the Daily regular session chart using the `request.security_lower_tf` function.

Below example script on a Daily chart will pull the afterhours data (post-market and next day pre-market data) into an array. The `not(session.ismarket)` imputes NA in the array for regular session data, after which you can use the `max.array` and `min.array` functions to get the afterhours High/Low data.

```
//@version=5
// only works on Daily chart
indicator("AfterHours Data", overlay = true)
t = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.extended)
arrH = request.security_lower_tf(t, '30', not(session.ismarket) ? high : na)
arrL = request.security_lower_tf(t, '30', not(session.ismarket) ? low : na)
maxH = array.max(arrH)
minL = array.min(arrL)
```

Taking this one step further, below script uses the AfterHours H/L to a) plot afterhours High/Lows on the Daily chart and b) show afterhours price change spikes (>10% change from close as default, but can be changed as desired).

```
version=5
// only works on Daily chart
indicator("AfterHours Spike Detector", shorttitle="AftHours",overlay = true)

//Inputs
showAftHL = input(true, "Show AfterHours H/L")
showAftSp = input(true, "Show AfterHours Spikes")
mult = input (10, "Spike Change % Threshold")
t = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.extended)
arrH  = request.security_lower_tf(t, '30', not(session.ismarket) ? high : na)
arrL  = request.security_lower_tf(t, '30', not(session.ismarket) ? low : na)

//Calculations
maxH = array.max(arrH)
minL = array.min(arrL)
Up = (maxH/close-1)*100
Dw = (minL/close-1)*100
Op1 = (open/maxH[1]-1)*100
Op2 = (open/minL[1]-1)*100

//Conditions
c01 = maxH < (high * (1+mult/100)) ? na: maxH
c02 = minL > (low * (1-mult/100)) ? na : minL

//Labels
txt1 = '+' + str.tostring(Up, '#') + '%'
txt2 = str.tostring(Dw, '#') + '%'
txt3 = Op1>0 ? '+' + str.tostring(Op1, '#') + '%': str.tostring(Op1, '#') + '%'
txt4 = Op2>0 ? '+' + str.tostring(Op2, '#') + '%': str.tostring(Op2, '#') + '%' 

//Plots
plot (not(showAftHL) ? na: maxH, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.aqua, linewidth=5, 
 display=display.pane+display.status_line)
plot (not(showAftHL) ? na: minL, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.orange, linewidth=5,
 display=display.pane+display.status_line)

plotshape(not (showAftSp and c01) ? na: maxH, style=shape.flag,
 color=color.new(color.blue,0), location=location.top, size=size.small, display=display.pane)
plotshape(not (showAftSp and c02) ? na: minL, style=shape.flag, 
 color=color.new(color.blue,0), location=location.bottom, size=size.small, display=display.pane)

if showAftSp
    label.new(not c01 ? na: bar_index, na, txt1, color=color.black, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
    label.new(not c02 ? na: bar_index, na, txt2, color=color.black, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
    label.new(not c01[1] ? na: bar_index, na, txt3, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
    label.new(not c02[1] ? na: bar_index, na, txt4, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
```

And it looks something like this (see below link to image of chart example):

- blue and orange circles are the afterhours High/Lows
- blue flags shows days with significant afterhours price changes
- black label shows the signficiant price change (% change from close to afterhours high/low)
- blue label shows what happens to the price change spike (% change from afterhours high/low to next day regular session open)

Below is also the link to this indicator on tradingview.

[Daily Chart with AfterHours High/Lows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TPWf.png)

[TradingView indicator - AfterHours Spike Detector](https://www.tradingview.com/script/o6z7iAtx-AfterHours-Spike-Detector/)